# Class cannot be used as type parameter in the generic type or method, there is no implicit reference conversion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generics, inheritance

I am building (attempting to build) generic Repository, Task, and Controllers for my MVC 4 project and using it to learn generics and interfaces. I've gotten pretty far, but stuck on this error. CustomerContactsListViewModel does inherit from IViewModelList, which is why I am perplexed.

Error:

```
The type 'OTIS.AppServ.OrderMgmt.ViewModels.CustomerContactsListViewModel' cannot be used as type parameter 'TViewModelList' in the generic type or method 'OTIS.AppServ.BaseAppServGrid<TRepository,TViewModelSingle,TViewModelList>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'OTIS.AppServ.OrderMgmt.ViewModels.CustomerContactsListViewModel' to 'OTIS.AppServ.IViewModelList<OTIS.domain.OrderMgmt.Customer,OTIS.AppServ.OrderMgmt.ViewModels.CustomerContactsListViewModel>'.
```

The interface:

```
public interface IViewModelList<TClass, TViewModelList>
    {
        IEnumerable<TClass> ConvertViewModelToClass(IEnumerable<TViewModelList> entityList);
        IEnumerable<TViewModelList> ConvertClassToViewModel(IEnumerable<TClass> entityList);
    }
```

The View Model that inherits the Interface:

```
    public class CustomerContactsListViewModel : IViewModelList<CustomerContact, CustomerContactsListViewModel>, IEntity
```

Generic Task (Application Services) class being inherited:

```
public class BaseAppServGrid<TRepository, TViewModelSingle, TViewModelList> : BaseAppServ<TRepository, TViewModelSingle>
            where TRepository : class, IEntity, IAuditStamps, new()
            where TViewModelSingle : class, IViewModelSingle<TRepository, TViewModelSingle>, new()
            where TViewModelList : class, IEntity, IViewModelList<TRepository, TViewModelList>, new()
```

The specific Task/App services class trying to inherit the Base, which throws the error:

```
public class ManageCustomersAppServ : BaseAppServGrid<Customer, CustomerViewModel, CustomerContactsListViewModel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `CustomerContactsListViewModel` you have implemented the first parameter of `IViewModelList` to be of type `CustomerContact`.

However, the class `ManageCustomersAppServ` has been declared with type `Customer`.

So

```
IViewModelList<Customer, CustomerContactsListViewModel>
```

is not assignable to

```
IViewModelList<CustomerContact, CustomerContactsListViewModel>
```

You need to either:

1. Change `BaseAppServGrid` to take another generic parameter like so:

   ```
   public class BaseAppServGrid<TModel, TRepository, TViewModelSingle, TViewModelList> :
       BaseAppServ<TRepository, TViewModelSingle>
       where TRepository : class, IEntity, IAuditStamps, new()
       where TViewModelSingle : class, IViewModelSingle<TRepository, TViewModelSingle>, new()
       where TViewModelList : class, IEntity, IViewModelList<TModel, TViewModelList>, new()

   public class ManageCustomersAppServ : BaseAppServGrid<CustomerContact, Customer, CustomerViewModel, CustomerContactsListViewModel>
   ```
2. Review whether Customer *and* CustomerContact can derive from some IRepository interface/class, if that was your intention when you passed Customer to a generic param called "TRepository".

Comment: Thanks Frank! With all these layers of generics, things were getting tricky!